# Loop over list in list in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I've a simple multi level list in Ansible:

```
        elements:
       - 'aaaa':
          - '1111'
          - '2222'
       - 'bbbb':
          - '3333'
          - '4444'
```

My template looks like:

```
    {% for level1 in elements %}
      {% for level2 in level1 %}
          {{ level2 }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

And the output is:

```
    aaaa
      bbbb
```

But I want to have someting similar to:

> aaaa: 1111 2222 bbbb: 3333 4444

How to modify this jinja joop to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*want to have something similar to*"**

```yaml
    aaaa: 1111 2222 bbbb: 3333 4444
```

A: The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for level1 in elements %}{{ level1.keys()|first }}:
          {%- for v in level1.values()|first %} {{ v }}
          {%- endfor %} {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
    aaaa: 1111 2222 bbbb: 3333 4444
```

Answer (score 2):

So Basically you have to iterate through `items` of `level1`.

**Updated Jinja2 `Query` is**

```
{%- for level1 in elements -%}
 {%- for key, value in level1.iteritems() -%}
     {{ key }}: {{ value|join(' ') }}
 {%- endfor -%}
{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

**Output :**

```
aaaa: 1111 2222 bbbb: 3333 4444
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not working. The output is: ('aaaa', ['1111', '2222'])...

Comment: @Janek Updated answer. Thanks.